# Отображение бокового меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, ul

На сайте https://positronica.ru/ (прошу прощения, что привожу конкретный сайт, но очень нужно разобраться именно с этим сайтом) есть следуюшее меню

```css
.menu .dropdown-menu-left__title_link,
.menu .dropdown-menu.pz_menu .block-text>li a.dropdown-menu-left__title_link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #84c427;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body dropdown open" id="menu">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu pz_menu">
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu" data-sectioncode="pzkitchen">
      <a href="https://krasnodar.positronica.ru/catalog/pzkitchen/" class="dropdown-toggle pzkitchen">
                            Бытовая техника для кухни                    </a>
      <span class="arrow--mobile arrow--right"></span>
      <div class="dropdown-menu-left" style="top: -60px; min-height: 799px;">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-left__title">
          <span class="arrow--mobile arrow--left"></span>
          <a href="https://krasnodar.positronica.ru/catalog/pzkitchen/" class="dropdown-menu-left__title_link">
                                    Бытовая техника для кухни                            </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="block-text">
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu" data-sectioncode="filtry_dlya_vody">
            <a href="https://krasnodar.positronica.ru/catalog/filtry_dlya_vody/">Фильтры и кулеры для воды</a>
            <span class="arrow--mobile arrow--right"></span>
            <ul>
              <div class="dropdown-menu-left__title">
                <span class="arrow--mobile arrow--left"></span>
                <a href="https://krasnodar.positronica.ru/catalog/filtry_dlya_vody/" class="dropdown-menu-left__title_link">
                                        Фильтры и кулеры для воды                                </a>
              </div>
              <li data-sectioncode="akvafiltrya">
                <a href="https://krasnodar.positronica.ru/catalog/akvafiltrya/">Аквафильтры</a>
              </li>
              <li data-sectioncode="akvafiltrykart">
                <a href="https://krasnodar.positronica.ru/catalog/akvafiltrykart/">Картриджи для аквафильтров</a>
              </li>
              <li data-sectioncode="kulery_dlya_vody">
                <a href="https://krasnodar.positronica.ru/catalog/kulery_dlya_vody/">Кулеры для воды</a>
              </li>
              <li data-sectioncode="pompy">
                <a href="https://krasnodar.positronica.ru/catalog/pompy/">Помпы и аксессуары</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

// Другие пункты меню из выпадающего меню, вызываемого из пункта меню ***Каталог товаров -> Бытовая техника для кухни***

</ul> //(закрывающий тег для .block-text, относящийся к пункту меню ***Каталог товаров -> Бытовая техника для кухни***)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня после копирования этого кода почему-то не отображается боковое меню, завернутое внутрь `ul.block-text`. В чем причина?

Есть зацепка, что #84c427 (светло-зеленый) - это цвет, в который окрашивается пункт меню из Каталога товаров (см. рисунок выше - Бытовая техника для кухни) и также происходит выпадение бокового меню.

Есть следующий код js (в котором фигурирует #84c427)

```js
.menu .dropdown-menu-left__title_link,
.menu .dropdown-menu.pz_menu .block-text > li a.dropdown-menu-left__title_link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #84c427;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Может вы приведёте минимально воспроизводимый код, а не огрызки от него?

Comment: @ArchDemon прояснил?

Comment: Там 100% задействован JavaScript, вы его не скипировали, потому и не работает.

Comment: Нет не прояснили. Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" и скажите, совпадает ли результат выполнения с картинкой, которую вы добавили в вопрос? И html комментарии помечаются не через `//`. Пора бы знать азы